# sklearn.linear_model LogisticRegression classifier training

Tags: python, nltk, logistic-regression

I am trying to use LogisticRegression classifier for the use case below.

```
corpus = [
        {
            classifier: "appt-count",
            text: "How many appointments I have for today?"
        },
        {
            classifier: "appt-count",
            text: "What is my total appointments for today?"
        },
        {
            classifier: "appt-list",
            text: "What are all my appointments today?"
        },
        {
            classifier: "appt-list",
            text: "Call you tell me my appointments today?"
        },
        {
            classifier: "appt-view",
            text: "What is my next appointment?"
        },
        {
            classifier: "appt-view",
            text: "What is my appointment after lunch?"
        },
        {
            classifier: "appt-view",
            text: "What is my first appointment today?"
        },
        {
            classifier: "appt-view",
            text: "What is my last appointment today?"
        }
    ]
```

Here, When user enter text, it is supposed to return the corresponding classifier.

```
import nltk
import pickle
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from nltk.stem import PorterStemmer, WordNetLemmatizer
from nltk.tokenize import sent_tokenize, word_tokenize
from nltk.classify import ClassifierI

from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression, SGDClassifier
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer,TfidfVectorizer

training = []
ps = PorterStemmer()
lemmatizer = WordNetLemmatizer()

df=pd.read_json("/../train_data.json", orient="records")
#print(df)
for name, text in zip(df['classifier'], df['text']):
  words = word_tokenize(text)
  stemWord = [ps.stem(w.lower()) for w in words]
  training.append([stemWord , name])

training = np.array(training, dtype=object)
train_x = list([training[:,0])
train_y = list(training[:,1])

print("Training data created")

classifier = LogisticRegression()

classifier.fit(train_x,train_y)

testInput = "How many appointments for today?"
print(classifier.predict(text.split()))
```

Here, I am getting error in classifier.fit line. Not sure how to train with the classifier and use the model for the prediction.